# Restkit, sending post data with loadObjectsAtResourcePath

Tags: cocoa-touch, restkit

If i am making a request with restkit i can use the shared client to send post parameters.
How can i do the same with shared Object manager, there seems to be no function to post data when objects are requested.

To re-iterate, am looking to send some post data when i am using loadObjectsAtResourcePath

Thanks

Comment: As pointed out by jverdi, i have tried using blocks, but any code inside the block does'nt seem to be executing

[objManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:url delegate:self block:^(RKObjectLoader* loader){ DDLogVerbose(@"Mapping objects from url %@",url); loader.objectMapping=postMapping; loader.method=RKRequestMethodPOST; RKParams *params=[RKParams params]; [params setValue:@"iPhone3u48gn39bndkthb34528dgbnjs398shbg34" forParam:@"token"]; loader.params=params; }];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must you use loadObjectsAtResourcePath? Here's what I use to send POST requests to my server

```
    RKParams* params = [RKParams params];
    [params setValue:@"The text" forParam:@"text"];

    RKClient* myClient = [RKClient sharedClient];
    [myClient post:resourceURL params:params delegate:self];
```

And you get your response back with

```
    - (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response
```

PS: Just found this link: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Posting-NSDictionary-as-JSON

Comment: I have to use loadOBjectsResourcePath since am doing some json mapping, i am not sure if json mapping can be done without using loadObjectsAtResourcePath. Thank your for pointing it out, but i already have been posting data successfully, just that i do not know how to do it with loadObjectsAtResourcePath

Comment: I've not tried this but with my method you will get your "- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response" call made and from there you should be able to call [response parsedBody] which the docs say: "Return the response body parsed as JSON into an object" Worth a try...

Comment: RKClient* myClient = [RKClient sharedClient];
    [myClient post:resourceURL params:params delegate:self];  - will not parse the and return the objects nicely like loadObjectsAtResourcePath does

Answer (score 1):

You can use the block style object loader to customize the request:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/monkeys.json" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
     loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Monkey class]];
     loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
}];
```

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Code/ObjectMapping/RKObjectManager.h#L374

Comment: Thanks for the info jverdi, but for some reason i cant use that method. It keeps throwing errors, i have even updated my RestKit since it looks like it was added recently.Any help?

Comment: [objManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:url delegate:self block:^(RKObjectLoader* loader){
                DDLogVerbose(@"Mapping objects from url %@",url);
                loader.objectMapping=postMapping;
                loader.method=RKRequestMethodPOST;
                RKParams *params=[RKParams params];
                [params setValue:@"iPhone3u48gn39bndkthb34528dgbnjs398shbg34" forParam:@"token"];
                loader.params=params;                
            }];

The above code doesn't work, the code inside the block doesn't seem to be executed.

Comment: How can I cancel this request? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499281/using-restkit-use-block-to-load-object-when-and-how-to-cancel-the-request

Comment: RKObjectLoader, the parameter sent in through the block, is a subclass of RKRequest. Within the block, just store loader to an ivar that lives outside the block's scope. Then you can cancel it by calling [loader cancel] when you need to.