# Using RestKit, use block to load object, when and how to cancel the request?

Tags: ios, block, restkit

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"app/site_pattern" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
    [loader setObjectMapping:clientMappring];
    loader.delegate = self;
    shopLoader = loader;
}];
```

Above, I use the block function to load some data in my app, but when I pop this viewcontroller, I don't know when and how to cancel this request .

Any idea?

```
- (void)showSelectShop
{

    SelectShopViewController * selectShopViewController = [[SelectShopViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectShopViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectShopViewController animated:YES];
}
```

More:

I try to cancel it in the viewDidUnload

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [shopLoader cancel];
}
```

But it didn't work. I still getting error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [shopLoader cancel];
    shopLoader.delegate = nil;
    shopLoader = nil;
}
```

I still want to know if I don't want to cancel this request in viewWillDisappear, which function do those lines should be written in?

Comment: That would depend on why you want to cancel the request?

Comment: @jverdi If I want to cancel it when the controller is released, I should write these code in dealloc or didunload or others?

Comment: Try this in your viewWillUnload: [[RKClient sharedClient].requestQueue cancelRequestsWithDelegate:self];

Comment: @jverdi I am stil facing this problem. Record every loader's name cost a lot time.

Comment: You won't need to record all of the loaders if you place the code above in your viewWillUnload. This will cancel all requests which have their delegate set to the same object represented by self.